# Pointer conversion, cannot convert Two* to One*

Tags: c++, conversion-operator

Say I have two classes, One and Two. One and Two are essentially the same, but Two can convert into One.

```
#ifndef _ONE_H_
#define _ONE_H_

class One
{
private:
    float m_x;
    float m_y;

public:
    One();
    One(float x, float y);
};

#endif
#ifndef _TWO_H_
#define _TWO_H_

#include "One.h"

class Two
{
private:
    float m_x;
    float m_y;

public:
    Two();
    Two(float x, float y);
    operator One() { return One(m_x, m_y); }
    operator One* () { return &One(m_x, m_y); }
    operator One& () const { return *this; }

    float GetX(void) { return m_x ;}
    float GetY(void) { return m_y ;}

    void Print();
};

#endif
```

Two has access to One, but One does not have access to Two. In the main.cpp I have:

```
One a(4.5f, 5.5f);

Two b(10.5, 7.5);

One * c = &b;
```

I get an error if I try to do the pointer of a One to the address of a Two. The error is "error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Two *' to 'One *'"

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this, if it is even possible. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Added a new line to Two.h with `operator One& () const { return *this; }`. The function I'm attempting to use to get this conversion operator to work is `void TestRefConstPrint(const One &testClass);` With main below, this presents a new error for "cannot convert parameter 1 from Two' to 'const One &'.

Inside main I do:

```
int main()
{
    Two b(10.5, 7.5);

    TestRefConstPrint(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conversion operators enable the conversions `Two -> One` and `Two -> One*`. You are trying to perform a different conversion, `Two* -> One*`.

To use your `operator One()` conversion operator to perform a `Two -> One` conversion, just do this:

```
One c = b;
```

---

If you really want to do a `Two* -> One*` conversion, you can, with an explicit cast:

```
One * c = (One *)&b;
```

or using C++-style casts:

```
One * c = reinterpret_cast<One *>(&b);
```

Note, however, that this does not use either of your conversion operators, and does a very different thing from the `Two -> One` conversion: it does not create a new object, it makes a pointer-to-`One` that points to the memory occupied by a `Two` object. This is generally a bad idea, and it's unlikely that you want to do this.

---

Finally, a comment about your `operator One*()`: it returns a dangling pointer (a pointer to a local variable which goes out of scope when the function returns). I assume you wrote it in your attempt to get the `Two* -> One*` conversion to work. You should remove it because it does not do what you want.

Comment: So is there any way to make it into an automatic function with an operator conversion? So when I do that it'll automatically do the reinterpret_cast?

Comment: @jamby: No. I would strongly recommend you perform value conversion (`One c = b`) instead, which uses your first conversion operator.

Comment: @jamby: I suppose you could derive `Two` from `One` (and get rid of `Two`'s data members). Then a `Two*` would convert implicitly to a `One*`. It's hard to say whether that would be appropriate without knowing more context, though my gut feeling says no.

Comment: Another question, what do I need to do for conversion operator for changing to a reference?

Say I have `void TestRefPrint(One &testClass);` and pass it the b. It shoots back an error for `error C2664: 'TestRefPrint' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Two' to 'One &'`.

Not exactly sure what operator is needed, maybe `operator One& ()`? But I'm not sure what would go into the function in terms of returning the answer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @jamby: A named `One` variable can be passed to a function that expects a `One&` argument, but a temporary `One` variable cannot. So just save the result of the conversion operator in a named variable, as in: `Two two; ... One one = two; TestRefPrint(one);`.

Comment: @jamby: Note that if `TestRefPrint` does not change the `One` variable that it gets passed, then you can change its argument to be `const One&` rather than `One&`, and then you can pass a temporary to it.

Comment: I have a conversion operator of `operator One&() { return reinterpret_cast<One&>(*this); }` inside my Two.h. This works fine for non-const parameters that require a One&, but if it requires a const One&, I received an error stating `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Two' to 'const One &'`.

Really at a loss on what to do.

Comment: @jamby: I can't reproduce your error. Please post a complete example.

Comment: Well I'm trying to get it to work with the function `void TestRefConstPrint(const One &testClass);`. I use the same `Two b(10.5, 7.5);` and then call `TestRefConstPrint(b);` to which I get the error for it. The conversion operator I use is `operator One& () const { return *this; }` inside Two.h but that's because I can't get anything else for it to work. Not exactly sure what the conversion operator should be for this.

Comment: @jamby: What compiler are you using? It works fine for me with GCC 4.5 and 4.6 (then again, I'm not sure I'm trying the same thing as you, because you haven't posted a **complete** example).

Comment: Sorry. I'm using Visual Studio 2008. I've edited my original problem up top to include the line in Two.h and added what I do in main. Hope this is helps.

Comment: @jamby: Your code compiles fine with three different compilers: GCC, clang, and Comeau. I'm afraid I don't have Visual Studio at hand to try with that. It's possible that you've found a bug in Visual Studio. As a workaround, you could try casting explicitly, or writing an overload of `TestRefConstPrint` that takes a `const Two&` parameter.